# Spring Data MongoDB Field Converter: Any way to pass a parameter?

Tags: java, mongodb, jackson, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

When our application is loading a DBOject/Document instance from our MongoDB, we need to convert all of the UTC dates in it into ZoneDateTime values using the zoneIdName, which is within the DBObject/Document instance.  We have a lot of Date fields in the DBObject, so I'd like to avoid having to implement a DBOject level Spring Data MongoDB Converter.

Is it possible to use a DBOject field level Spring Data MongoDB Converter, such as the following, which uses a field in the DBObject (i.e. zoneIdName), to be able to perform the conversion to a ZoneDateTime?  If not, I will have to implement an object-level Converter, but it will be tedious...

Thank you for your interest and time.

```
class ZonedDateTimeReadConverter :
    Converter<Date, ZonedDateTime> {

    override fun convert(date: Date): ZonedDateTime {
        // Need to replace "America/LosAngeles" with 
        // a value from a field in the object being processed.
        return date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("America/LosAngeles"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

seems that converter for whole object is only option